# Is there any way to include regressors in tbats function in r?

Tags: r, forecasting

I knew that tbtas could not consider regressor in r but I knew that Dr Hydman group were working to include this feature. I just wanted to know if it is still under work.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R, but not about programming in R per se & does not have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) (& thus would be closed on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a time line of somebody's development of an R package. It does not belong anywhere in the SE universe -- an email to the developer(s) should have sufficed.

Comment: The author of TBATS Rob Hyndman has addressed this question in his recent [blog](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tbats-with-regressors/#disqus_thread)

Answer (score 1):

The help page to `tbats()` notes that you can specify parameters that are passed through to `auto.arima()`, which models the errors.

EDIT: I assume the OP contacted Rob Hyndman, the maintainer of the `forecast` package. [Rob writes that this information from the help page is actually misleading.](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tbats-with-regressors/) `tbats()` does not and likely will never include covariates - it will not complain if they are provided, but they will be silently ignored.

Rob recommends using `auto.arima()` if external regressors are required to be used. The help page to `auto.arima()` notes that you can specify external regressors by feeding a vector or matrix to the `xreg` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your note. I already implemented your code for my data and it improved my forecasts a little not significantly. Although I included daily seasonality to capture lower values for weekend, but it seems that the model is not properly smoothing the forecast for weekend. I dont know if I have to include dummy variables for days of a week rather than including daily seasonality.

Comment: On the one hand, you can try multiple different models, as you propose. On the other hand, sometimes it simply is hard to improve on a given forecast, if the series is inherently not very [forecastable](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116599/how-can-one-say-if-a-model-is-poor-based-on-rmse-value/116602#116602). Good luck!

Comment: Stephan I tried tbats with regresor for multiple data sets and it did not work. I mean the fitted model with regressor and no regressor were the same. Are you sure tbats work with regressor?

Comment: It's possible that `auto.arima()` removes regressors, e.g., by AIC. A quick glance at [the paper referenced in the `auto.arima` help page](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v27/i03/paper) does not tell how external regressors are handled. You may possibly have found a bug. Best to step through the source code and/or contact the package maintainer, Rob Hyndman.

Comment: Honestly I saw in one of Dr Hyndman's post that he said right now tbats can not handle regressors and they are working on it. So I thought its still under work and they have not published the code yet but Im not sure about it at all.

Comment: Contact him and ask. Explain that the `tbats` help page refers to the `auto.arima` help page, which claims that `auto.arima` *can* handle regressors.

Comment: I've updated the man file to indicate which arguments for auto.arima() can be passed from tbats().